# Проблема с mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite, файловая-система

Есть структура папок:

> ```
> /framework
> /web
>     /index.php
>     /images
>     /css
> /src
> /app
> ```

Имеется .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /web/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

И есть файл layout.html.php, в котором пути к картинкам прописаны так: `<img src="/images/img.png" />`. Ясное дело, что работает все это не так, как хотелось бы. А именно, для правильной работы нужно писать: `<img src="/web/images/img.png" />`.

Что нужно изменить в настройках mod_rewrite, я не очень пойму. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Где лежит htaccess и где layout.html.php?

Comment: .htaccess я пробовал ложить как в корень, так и в /web. Расположение же layout.html.php особой роли играть не должно, ведь пути к картинкам прописаны от корня сайта. Но если что - он в /src/views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сам хост надо настраивать на /web, тогда картинки и файлы будут подгружаться через /images/.

web для того и делают, чтоб файлы фреймворка были недоступны.

Comment: Спасибо, сменил настройку виртуального домена, все получилось :)